# Как сделать такую рамку вокруг картинки?

Tags: css

Как сделать такую рамку вокруг картинки?
[image]

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?q=round+border+css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
img.rounded {
    border-radius: 100px; /* половина длины картинки */
    border: 5px solid #3333cc; /* например */
}
```

Картинка (или контейнер) — квадрат

Comment: @densmith если поставить border-radius половину длины картинки, то рамка не круглая.

Comment: для этого необходимо ставить border-radius: 50% or добавить половину border

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8usc28a0/

Comment: @soledar10 я вижу, что Ваш пример прекрасно работает. Но у меня почему-то рамка не становиться как положено! http://dental2.brandivo.com

Comment: вы задаете контейнеру border, а необходимо img - т.е там контейнер и не нужен